# Which Google-Map-API is suitable for my usage?

Tags: java, python, node.js, web, google-maps-api-3

I am not a web developer and I have not any experience about Web Software Development.

I need to prepare a web site, which get location of some devices every 15 seconds and show location of them on Google Map. To real time connection I need to use TCP or UDP, and I preferred to use NodeJS but I am not sure which Google service API is more suitable for me.

As I checked the Google Web Services, there is a service which is called "[Google Maps Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro#overview)". This API is interested for me but Google says it is available as part of Java or Python.

So I need to know:

1. Is any advantages
       to use Road Map API?
2. Do you suggest me I use Java or Python and
       don't use NodeJS?
3. Can I combine Java or Python with NodeJS ?

And At the end, I am glad to hear any recommend from experienced members.